# Accessing shell variables inside 'sudo' block : export doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, sudo

I am writing a script to fix a missing 'F' letter in a mail log file. The mail log file is continuously updating. I am getting a file name, after that I am doing 'sudo su' to get superuser access. Inside sudo, I am fixing a  missing 'F'. However, I am unable to use that file name inside sudo block. Please can anyone help me how I can export these shell variables inside sudo? I tried using export but it's not working. The code block I have created is as follows-

```
 #Script to solve F issue
#----------------------------------------
#By Kapil Shirsath
#----------------------------------------

cd /var/spool/mail        #mail files reside in mail folder
echo "Entered in mail folder"

filename=`ls -lrt  99999*| sort -k 5 -rn | head -1 | tr -s " " "," | cut -d "," -f "8"`    # this will list the file with maximum size`

echo "File with maximum size is  $filename"
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Is it the file expected?(y/n)"
read choice
if test $choice == "n"
then
    echo "Exiting...."
    exit;
fi;

c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    echo $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"

sudo su<<'HERE'   #this will give you super user permissions
echo "Got root access"
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=`head -1 $filename`
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
HERE


c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"  
else
    echo "Not finding the missing 'F' ! !! Kindly check with your system "
    exit;
fi;
```

Comment: You should allow for the sudo password to be input, which you do not. Are you sure you are root when you run this script?

Comment: Yes.I am sure MariusMatutiae . I get root access when I run this script.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Did you find an answer?

Comment: Don't use quote around `HERE`. Use it like: `sudo su<<HERE`

Comment: @anubhava : Thanks Anubhava . I will try it within a minute. Just small query- Doing it will allow me to create a variable inside sudo block? e.g. firstline=`head -1 $filename`?

Comment: @anubhava  Problem solved to some extent. The line head -1 $filename is giving me the first line of file, but the firstline=head -1 $filename is not executing properly saying 'unexpected end of file'. The value inside the firstline variable is null.

Comment: Try `firstline=$(head -1 "$filename")`

Comment: @anubhava : Hi Anubhava, I tried your suggestion. But I am getting error as 'bash: line 3: Shirsath: command not found'. The first line in my file is  #Kapil Shirsath

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use bash's *[here strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)*:

```
sudo su <<< HERE
```

(you're using `<<` instead of `<<<`).

Either way, it's not a good idea to have an "auto-`sudo`" command inside a script, since you're exposing a delicate password as plain text. You should just run that script as root (either with `sudo` or `su -c`).

Even better, you should run the script with the lesser common user permissions (maybe `mail`?).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 simple possibilities. The first is to stop quoting the block of
text being passed into `sudo su`, by removing the quotes from the `<<`
terminator string (ie use `<<HERE`). In this case all $variable and
back-tick (``) executions inside the block will be evaluated before being passed
to `sudo su`, so you need to escape them with `\$` for example. The result is:

```
sudo su <<HERE   #this will give you super user permissions
echo "Got root access"
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=\$(head -1 $filename)
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test \$? -eq 0
then
ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
HERE
```

The 2nd possibility is easier to read. Simply apply sudo only where
necessary. You no longer need a block of code. The result is:

```
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
sudo head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=`sudo head -1 $filename`
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
sudo ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
```